# launch a .stl file

Tags: ros, gazebo, roslaunch, stl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros Users:

I have a .stl file and I just would like to launch in a gazebo empty world with a .launch. How con I do that?

Thanks a lot !

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/219390/launch-a-.stl-file/) by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 149 on 2015-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can either make your stl part of a SDF (Gazebo) model or of a URDF model. The first method is fully independent of ROS and [described here on gazebosim.org](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=build_model&cat=build_robot).

An example for spawning a stl via a URDF model is [here](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/environment_models). The `urdf`  folder contains the model (which is referencing a stl file in the `Media` folder) and the `launch` folder contains launch files for spawning the model into a Gazebo scene.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alvaro Salcedo](https://answers.ros.org/users/22155/alvaro-salcedo/) on 2015-10-20**:
Thanks a lot @Stefan Kohlbrecher ! I have fixed it!
But now I have another problem... please have a look at http://answers.ros.org/question/219467/textures-in-a-stl-file/ because maybe you can help me.
Thanks a lot again

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Open the file in SolidWorks and export to URDF using [this](http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter) plug-in. This URDF file can be read in Gazebo. You can find the details and procedure in following links
[Solidworks teacher blog](http://blogs.solidworks.com/teacher/2014/05/solidworks-to-gazebo-robot-simulation.html), [Design for gazebo](http://blogs.solidworks.com/teacher/wp-content/uploads/sites/3/WPI-Robotics-SolidWorks-to-Gazebo.pdf), [Willow Garage](http://www.willowgarage.com/blog/2012/10/18/exporting-urdfs-directly-solidworks).

---

Originally posted by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) with karma: 173 on 2015-10-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1